# NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 100

Tags: linux, kernel, centos6

Today,I have found

> kernel: NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 100

in `/var/log/messages`. os version is CentOS-6.5(64bits).

I searched through google and found this link(https://kb.plesk.com/en/119599).
It said

> These messages indicate that the system puts CPUs to sleep state
>   instead of processing some software interrupt

But I still doubt whether this will cause harm to the server
Could anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, CONFIG_NO_HZ_IDLE option enables a tickless idle system (a.k.a. “dynticks-idle system”).

In accordance with https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt

> There are situations in which idle CPUs cannot be permitted to enter either dyntick-idle mode or adaptive-tick mode, the most common being when that CPU has RCU callbacks pending.
>
> The CONFIG_RCU_FAST_NO_HZ=y Kconfig option may be used to cause such CPUs to enter dyntick-idle mode or adaptive-tick mode anyway.  In this case, a timer will awaken these CPUs every four jiffies in order to ensure that the RCU callbacks are processed in a timely fashion.
>
> Another approach is to offload RCU callback processing to "rcuo" kthreads using the CONFIG_RCU_NOCB_CPU=y Kconfig option.  The specific CPUs to offload may be selected via several methods…"

Therefore a solution could be just to rebuild the kernel with CONFIG_RCU_FAST_NO_HZ=y and/or disable dynamic ticks via the kernel parameter nohz=off ("never omit scheduling-clock ticks", this may have other side effects).